# 12.04 Install Confusion - Live CD Boots fine, installed system needs acpi=off to boot

Tags: 12.04, acpi

New Lenovo Z585 A10 laptop.

I can boot the 64 bit Live CD fine - Try Ubuntu - `dmesg` contains lots of acpi stuff, Suspend is available etc.

When I do the install I am unable to boot without **acpi=off** in kernel line.  Of course when booted I hav no suspend, no battery status etc...

Seems that casper is doing a bunch of things on the Live CD boot that I am not able to do with my install.

Help !!

Comment: I have the same problem. Found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12291012) but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

open up terminal

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
In the grub file, change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off` Save exit
`sudo update-grub` reboot and viola !

Comment: Well, yes that is what I did... but don't want to.  I want my on disk install to have the same capabilities as detected by the boot process off the livecd.

Comment: Oh okay have you tried booting with acpi=ht? Or nomodeset ?

Comment: Yes, with nomodeset but not with acpi=ht.  Will give it a try.

Comment: Tried acpi=ht and nothing.  Addedd nomodeset and at least saw text of the boot that stopped on an ACPI line. Thanks BTW.